# Fast count() intersection of two string arrays

Tags: c#, optimization, array-intersect

I need to count the number of elements corresponding to the intersection of two big arrays of strings and do it very fast.

I am using the following code:

```
arr1[i].Intersect(arr2[j]).Count()
```

For CPU Time, VS Profiler indicates

- 85.1% in `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count()`
- 0.3%  in `System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect()`

Unfortunately it might to take hours to do all work.

How to do it faster?

Comment: The numbers you got from the profiler are propably not "correct". Because the Intersect is not executed when you say .Intersect(), the whole query is exeuted when you say .Count(). That's the nature of LINQ. I suspect there is more work to be done when intersecting than when counting.
If you really need performance on this one, try to do it without LINQ.

Comment: If it's big enough, put it in a database, or create a cluster of computers/threads, maybe do some MapReduce..

Comment: Are you intersecting the strings in the `arr1` and `arr2` or each character from each string in `arr1` vs. each character from each string in `arr2`?

Comment: I hardly think this is your bottleneck. In my tests Intersect+Count on 2 arrays of 5 millions of strings (avg.length=60 char) takes ~3.5 seconds... How big are your arrays ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HashSet` with `arr2`

```
HashSet<string> arr2Set = new HashSet<string>(arr2);
arr1.Where(x=>arr2Set.Contains(x)).Count();
              ------------------
                      |
                      |->HashSet's contains method executes quickly using hash-based lookup..
```

Not considering the conversion from `arr2` to `arr2Set` ,this should be `O(n)`

Comment: This is the Best Way ! the most efficient.
This method is for Instersect. Is it possible to use the same principle for Union?

Comment: This gives incorrect answers in the case where `arr1` contains duplicate strings which also have duplicates in `arr2`. You'd need `Where(x => arr2Set.Remove(x))`.

Comment: Also, this `Contains` version ends up _slower_ if the arrays get larger - but the version with `Remove` _does_ seem to stay faster.

Comment: Just a syntax improvement - `arr1.Where(x=>arr2Set.Contains(x)).Count();` can be replaced with `arr1.Count(arr2Set.Contains);`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason why the profiler shows the time being consumed in `Count`, is that this is where the collection is actually enumerated (the `Intersect` is lazily evaluated and does not run before you need the result).

I believe `Intersect` should have some internal optimizations to make this reasonably fast, but you could try using a `HashSet<string>` so you are sure the intersect can be made without searching through the inner array for each element:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
set.IntersectWith(arr2);
int count = set.Count;
```

Comment: Bizarrely, in my test this ended up slower than both the original and my corrected version of `Some1`'s answer, when I would've expected it to be great.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm Intersect is probably N^2

to make it faster quicksort both arrays. and than traverse both arrays. counting intersections.

too lazy to test how fast it would be but should O(nlogn +n)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int arrsize = 1000000;
            Random rnd = new Random(42);
            string[] arr1 = new string[arrsize];
            string[] arr2 = new string[arrsize];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
            {
                arr1[i] = rnd.Next().ToString();
                arr2[i] = rnd.Next().ToString();
            }
            {
                var stamp = (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
                arr1.Intersect(arr2).Count();
                Console.WriteLine("array" + (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - stamp));
            }

        {

            HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
            var stamp = (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
            set.IntersectWith(arr2);
            int count = set.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("HashSet" + (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - stamp));
        }
            {
               var stamp = (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
                HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
                set.IntersectWith(arr2);
                int count = set.Count;
                Console.WriteLine("HashSet + new" + (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - stamp));
            }

            {
                var stamp = (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
                SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>(arr1);
                set.IntersectWith(arr2);
                int count = set.Count;
                Console.WriteLine("SortedSet +new " + (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - stamp));
            }

            {

                SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>(arr1);
                var stamp = (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
                set.IntersectWith(arr2);
                int count = set.Count;
                Console.WriteLine("SortedSet without new " + (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - stamp));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

results

array    914,637

HashSet   816,119

HashSet +new   1,150,978

SortedSet +new    16,173,836

SortedSet without new   7,946,709

so seems that best way is to keep a ready hash set.

Comment: Intersect in the linq extension is implemented O(n log n)

Comment: Intersect in HashSet is also implemented O(n log n), just looked in the disassembly

Comment: @user287107: that's not true. Both Intersect and HashSet use hash tables and so hashset is asymptotically `O(1)` and intersect is `O(n)`. Of course sometimes `O(logn)` complexity could be faster (it depends on gethashcode implementation, buckets and other factor), but they're not implemented using binarytrees or something with `O(logn)` complexity.

Comment: @user287107: http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.it/2010/03/runtime-complexity-of-net-generic.html

Comment: I know it could be faster, but just take a look at the implementation of the IntersectIterator class. the iterator does the following 1) create new set, 2) iterate through source1, add items to set 3) iterate through source2, if remove is successfull, yield return the element. the adding and removing is O(log n), and by the loop it is O(n log n)

Comment: @user287107: `Linq.Enumerable.Set` add and remove are `O(1)` operations (as for the `HashSet<>`), and by the loop is `O(n * 1) --> O(n)`

Comment: ok you're right, add and remove are **typical** O(1) operations, but that also implies that in the result it is not guaranteed O(n)

Comment: @user287107: yes, that's correct. "Big O" complexity means asymptotic behaviour, so as I said before methods with `O(logn)` can be faster sometimes. For example in case of many hash collisions...

Answer (score 0):

when you are working with sets, your complexity will be O((n log n)*(m log m)) or so,

i think this here should be faster, but i'm not sure if it is now O((n log n)+(m log m))

```
possible would be 
var Set1 = arr1[i].Distinct().ToArray(); // if necessary, if arr1 or arr2 could be not distinct
var Set2 = arr2[j].Distinct().ToArray();  

nCount = Set1.Count() + Set2.Count() - Set1.Append(Set2).Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a *HashSet* using the **smaller** array and then loop through the bigger one, incrementing a counter if the item it exists in the hashset.