# How does Fast count() Union of two string arrays

Tags: c#, optimization

In this topic [Fast count() intersection of two string arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900514/fast-count-intersection-of-two-string-arrays), *Some1.Kill.The.DJ* explains a very fast method for calculating the intersection of two arrays of strings.

This is :

```
HashSet<string> arr2Set = new HashSet<string>(arr2);
arr1.Where(x=>arr2Set.Contains(x)).Count();
```

In the same thing, how does Union?

Comment: I dont understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, that method shouldn't be any faster than the original, since it's essentially doing the same thing behind the scenes.

(Edit: It's not even *correct* in the case where `arr1` contains duplicate items that are also in `arr2`! It's also not always faster: I tried it on short arrays and it was, but tried it on longer arrays and it wasn't.)

A parallel for `Union` might be

```
HashSet<string> arr2Set = new HashSet<string>(arr2);
int unionSize = arr2Set.Count + arr1.Where(x=>arr2Set.Add(x)).Count();
```

but it really should be no different from doing

```
int unionSize = arr1.Union(arr2).Count();
```

If you're worried about performance, [read this first](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). By *trying* this version and timing the two, you could well end up with the original version being faster - I certainly did.

Comment: "Edit: It's not even correct in the case where arr1 contains duplicate items that are also in arr2!" -- A `HashSet` cannot contain duplicate items, can it?

Comment: @hvd No, but the source arrays can. In such a case, `Intersect` (as a set operation) discards all duplicates, but the hashset-version discards duplicates in `arr2` (fine) but counts all duplicates in `arr1` (not fine).

Comment: Ah, you're right, I misunderstood the question. Additionally, if duplicate items exist in `arr2`, they won't remain in `arr2Set`.

Comment: @hvd They won't remain, but that's OK - `Intersect` is supposed to ignore duplicates.

Comment: I was concerned about the case you mentioned, duplicates in `arr1`. It is no longer possible to check whether they were also duplicated in `arr2`. I do not know about `Enumerable.Intersect()` specifically, but generally, I would expect the intersection of [ 1, 2, 2, 3 ] and [ 2, 2, 3, 3 ] to be [ 2, 2, 3 ], not [ 2, 3 ].

Comment: @hvd The LINQ intersect/union/etc. are styled as "set operations", and they discard all duplicates; your kind of intersect is a little trickier to implement, but certainly possible.